# Can these variants of SAT/Tautology be actually pretty simple?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, satisfiability, co-np

There are 8 (very similiar) languages I'd like to discuss here:

- CNF SAT
- DNF SAT
- CNF No-SAT (Existence of a false assignment)
- DNF No-SAT
- CNF Tautology
- DNF Tautology
- CNF Contradiction
- DNF Contradiction

While CNF SAT is known to be $NPC$, my claim is that some of these languages are actually in $P$. The easiest one is DNF SAT. We arbitrarily select the first clause. It is of the form $l_{1,1} \wedge ... \wedge l_{1,k}$. We simply assign values to the boolean variables that appear among $l_{1,1} \wedge ... \wedge l_{1,k}$ in accordance to the $\neg$ or no $\neg$ they have in $l_{1,1} \wedge ... \wedge l_{1,k}$. This assignment yields a truth value for the first clause, and therefore for the entire DNF formula.

For DNF No-SAT, we iterate over the existing clauses. Each clause has a $1-1$ correspondence with an assignment, assuming it contains all variables. We can therefore iterate over all the (sorted by binary values) clauses, comparing each to the next (by binary value) assignment. If we found a mismatch, we know that we skipped a possible assignment. In other words, that skipped assignment is an assignment that gives false. It is important to note that while $2^{n-h}$ (some $h$) assignments might be checked here, this will only be the case if we have disqualified $2^{n-h}$ assignments so far, which means that the input DNF formula was very long! But my idea is less affective when a clause is allowed to use only part of the variables, then we can have a clause of the form $x_1\wedge x_n$ which actually represents $2^{n-2}$ possible assignments. So my approach here is lacking. But, in the case all variables must appear, my algorithm runs in linear time depending on the size of the NF formula.

I'll continue to CNF Tautology. This is the complementary language of DNF No-SAT. But I have a different approach here. A CNF is a tautology iff each clause is a tautology. A clause is a tautology iff it has some variable $x_i$ for which we have both $x_i$ and $\neg x_i$. This can be verified in linear time. Assuming what I said about having  $x_i$ and $\neg x_i$ is correct (I'm not entirely sure about that).

In other words, CNF Tautology is linear. Ofcourse, DNF Tautology is harder. How about CNF Contradiction? Or DNF Contradiction? (Whether a given CNF/DNF formula always admits false)

I don't expect any of this to solve SAT in polynomial time, as these are all basic ideas. But I'm wondering if:

1. All my algorithms are correct?
2. What is the classification of: CNF No-Sat, DNF No-Sat, DNF Contradiction?
3. Any conclusions from having such similar problems to the classical $NPC$ problem be actually in $P$?

Comment: We normally prefer that you ask only one question per post, so I suspect it would be better to ask a separate question about each language that you are unsure about.  We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, because they're unlikely to be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tip. I think mostly its that I'm just not 100% sure about my proposal for algorithms... As for the multiple languages, I thought it might be redundant to open up a different topic per language, as they are all a variant of SAT/Tautology, but if you think its better...

Comment: Yes, I think it's better, as the algorithm will be different in each case.  You might start by asking about one or two, and then using your experience with those to help you formulate the questions about any others that you are unsure about.